# Is there a way to simplify this equation, $\sqrt {5x-3} +\sqrt{4y+1} =0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to simplify this equation, $\sqrt {5x-3} +\sqrt{4y+1} =0    $ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $\sqrt {5x-3} \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{4y+1}  \ge 0$. From $\sqrt {5x-3} +\sqrt{4y+1} =0$ we get

$$\sqrt {5x-3}=0$$

and

$$\sqrt{4y+1}  =0.$$

Hence $x=3/5$ and $y=-1/4.$